# Getting full output from php system() function

Tags: php, c++, cmd

I have a problem with php system() function output. So here goes the code:

```
system("c:\\Dev-Cpp\\bin\\g++.exe c:\\wamp\\www\\hello.cpp -O3 -o c:\\wamp\\www\\hello.exe", $output);

echo $output;
```

So if my hello.cpp does compile I get 0, if it doesn't I get 1.

If I run the same thing from CMD instead of giving just 1 it gives me full error.

How can I get the full error with php system() function?

Answer (score 2):

You are only catching the return code of the program, which is normally an integer where `0` means 'success' and anything else is an error code.

If you want to catch the actual output of the program (i.e. [STDOUT and/or STDERR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)) You need to do one of these things:

- Use output buffering to capture the output of `system()`:

```
$command = "c:\\Dev-Cpp\\bin\\g++.exe c:\\wamp\\www\\hello.cpp -O3 -o c:\\wamp\\www\\hello.exe";
ob_start();
system($command, $returnCode);
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

- Use [`exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php), [`shell_exec()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) or [backticks](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php):

```
exec($command, $output, $returnCode);
// ...or...
$output = shell_exec($command);
// ...or...
$output = `$command`;
```

If you want to catch the output of STDERR (which I suspect you do), you may need to add `2>&1` to the end of your command string.

Alternatively, you may want to look at [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which is more complicated but can give you finer-grained control over the child process and how it executes/passes data back to you.